# Padding in a div which content is relatively moved upward

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if the question's title doesn't really make sense but it's a problem sort of difficult to describe with words when English is not your first language. The best way would be to show what I mean by a fiddle.

[jsFiddle - problem](http://jsfiddle.net/kdFgn/)

In this example I have a container `div` with `overflow: hidden` and some top padding. The relatively positioned `div` with `content` class in the project is scrolled by jQuery, but it's not relevant now. Let's say that the example shows a situation where the content has been scrolled down a little.

The `div` has moved upward and sadly the content "ignores" the container's padding, which is correct and expected html behaviour. However in this case I have to "prevent the padding from disappearing". The html structure must remain the same - the content `div` must be directly inside the container.

I came up with a solution using another `div` posing as "padding" by using absolute positioning and `z-index`.

[jsFiddle - solution?](http://jsfiddle.net/kdFgn/2/)

My question - is there a prettier way to achieve this result?

Comment: Given your constraints, I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only improvement I'd suggest is from a visual/design perspective:

Instead of having the solid white `#fff` in your `mask` class, perhaps an image with a gradient from transparent to background colour (white, in your case), so the text looks like it's going behind something rather than just getting "cut off".

Have uploaded a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kdFgn/30/